# Excel 2003 : How to lock the whole template except a few cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to lock the whole template/sheet except for a **few cells** that are to be filled manually.
To lock the template I used "Tools / Protection / Protect Sheet "

I am using Excel 2003 spreadsheets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is to select a cell that you want to be editable, choose Format/Cells, hit the "Protection" tab, and uncheck the box that says "Locked".

Note that this will have to be done *before* you protect the sheet.

Comment: For choosing `Format Cells` we can use Ctrl+1 ;).